# Regex for split only if all string are quoted

Tags: java, regex

Is there a way to return the delimiters for a split only if all strings are quoted using regex?

Considering that the string should be splitted by "-".

Using `((?<=")-(?="))` it matches the 2 `-` and that's ok with the following sample:
`"abc"-"123"-"zxc"`.

But the regex matches 2 `-` in the following samples when should not detect any `-`:

`abc"-"123"-"zxc"`

`"abc"-"123"-"zxc`

Using `-(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)` it matches the 2 `-` and that's ok with the following samples:
`"abc"-"123"-"zxc"`.

It does not match any `-` on the following samples and that's ok too:

`"abc"-"123"-"zxc`

`"abc"-"123"-zxc"`

But the regex matches 2 `-` in the following samples when should not detect any `-`:

`abc"-"123"-"zxc"`

`abc-"123"-"zxc"`

`"abc"-"123"-zxc`

I was thinking to apply 2 regex, if the string matches with `^"[\da-z\-"]*"$` I would apply the split with `((?<=")-(?="))` but I feel that there is a way that I haven't tried yet.

Comment: Do you want to match second `-` in `abc"-"123"-"zxc"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return values around the delimiters, you might use a capture group in combination with using the `\G` anchor.

```
\G("[^"]*")(?=(?:-"[^"]*")*$)(?:-|$)
```

**Explanation**

- `\G` Assert the position at the end of the previous match or at the start of the string
- `("[^"]*")` Match from a double quote till a double quote
- `(?=(?:-"[^"]*")*$)` Assert optional part of `-".."` at the right until the end of the string
- `(?:-|$)` Match either `-`, or end of string

See a [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TssXzj/1) or a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/xE5pf3)

In Java with doubled backslashes:

```
String regex = "\\G(\"[^\"]*\")(?=(?:-\"[^\"]*\")*$)(?:-|$)";
```

**For example**

```
String strings[] = {
    "\"abc\"-\"123\"-\"zxc1\"",
    "\"abc\"-\"123\"-\"zxc2",
    "\"abc\"-\"123\"-zxc3\"",
    "abc\"-\"123\"-\"zxc4\"",
    "\"abc\"-\"123\"-\"zxc5",
    "abc\"-\"123\"-\"zxc6\"",
    "abc-\"123\"-\"zxc7\"",
    "\"abc\"-\"123\"-zxc8"
};
String regex = "\\G(\"[^\"]*\")(?=(?:-\"[^\"]*\")*$)(?:-|$)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
for (String s : strings) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
"abc"
"123"
"zxc1"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use `String#matches` with the following pattern:

```
"[^"]+"(?:-"[^"]+")*
```

Script:

```java
String input = "\"abc\"-\"123\"-\"zxc\"";
if (input.matches("\"[^\"]+\"(?:-\"[^\"]+\")*")) {
    System.out.println("MATCH");  // prints MATCH
}

String input = "abc\"-\"123\"-\"zxc\"";  // missing leading quote
if (input.matches("\"[^\"]+\"(?:-\"[^\"]+\")*")) {
    System.out.println("MATCH");  // does not print
}
```

Comment: He wants to split the string!

Comment: No, I disagree with your comment.  Splitting the string and validating it are two different things.  My read of the OP is that the main difficulty is with validation.